# AtTask API - Creating access rules with the "share" operation

Tags: attask

I'm trying to use the following URI to add EDIT access to a team on a project:

> https://mysite.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/v4.0/project/54983c34002ee72d8e3869b29dcaa625/share?method=PUT&sessionID=0096e9b9f1cc4471b911c7a49b917cec&accessorID=53bb2da40003442310e8946bff9ce324&accessorObjCode=TEAMOB&coreAction=EDIT

This seems to follow the form specified [in the API docs](https://developers.attask.com/api-docs/#sharing_objects), but it's giving me the error **APIModel V4_0 does not support share operation**. The API docs specifically say to use v4.0 in the URI, so why am I getting this error? Is something else wrong with the URI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no action named 'share' for projects in AtTask API. That's why your code doesn't work.

As an alternative way, you can first get all `accessRules` of your project, add new accessRule object to received array and then edit your project (PUT method) to apply new array of accessRules.

To get all accessRules make a call to:

```
https://mysite.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/v4.0/project/54983c34002ee72d8e3869b29dcaa625?fields=accessRules:*
```

In a response you will get an array of `ACSRUL` objects under `accessRules` key. Add new object to that array:

```
{
    objCode: 'ACSRUL',
    securityObjID: '54983c34002ee72d8e3869b29dcaa625', //your project
    securityObjCode: 'PROJ',
    accessorID: '53bb2da40003442310e8946bff9ce324', //team to be shared with
    accessorObjCode: 'TEAMOB',
    coreAction: 'EDIT',
    secondaryActions: [],
    forbiddenActions: []
}
```

Then update your project (see [Nested Updates](https://developers.attask.com/api-docs/#NestedUpdates))

```
PUT /attask/api/project/54983c34002ee72d8e3869b29dcaa625?updates= 
{
    accessRules: [ ... ] //array of access rules
}
```

Comment: Cool, this will work. Thanks! But why is "share" in the API docs if it's not actually supported?

Comment: Also, I'm getting a "403 forbidden" error when I try this method. The user I'm logging in with via the API has System Administrator privileges and can modify the access rules in the AtTask GUI, and I made sure to include the SessionID in the URI. Any idea why I'm getting that error?

Comment: @SuperSpry, please contact customer support and let them log an issue regarding missing share method in API. One thing I know for sure, if you receive "APIModel V4_0 does not support share operation" error, that means "share" operation is not exposed to API. Maybe it was exposed at some point, and then something changed and docs were not updated, I don't know.

Comment: Will do. Do you have any idea why I'd be getting a 403 error with the method you suggested?

Comment: System Administrator should be able to do everything. You have to make sure that all parameters are passed to API properly (it should be urlencoded, serialized JSON object).

Comment: Ah, it was a URL encoding problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue where the Sharing was not exposed to the Api v4.0 but this was fixed over the weekend. Your initial call should work now.

Comment: Thanks!!  Its working for me. But I also want to delete ProjectUser for specific project.